# Cluster points stored in vector c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have the following vector

```
{ Point(100, 200), Point(101, 202), Point(200, 200), 
  Point(201, 202), Point(203, 204), Point(100, 400), 
  Point(102, 402), Point(200, 400), Point(202, 401), Point(205, 405) };
```

The vector contains vertices of a rectangle and some neighboring points of vertices. I need to extract the rectangle vertices from these points meaning for Point `( 100, 200 )` and `( 101, 102 )` I just need one of them. Then for Points `( 200, 200 )`, `( 201, 202 )` , `( 203, 204 )` I just need one point (may be average or center of these neighbors) and so forth. It may be a triangle with similar distribution or just a line with two groups or a point with a single group.

Kindly guide me how can I achieve this? Should I use Kmeans or if yes how? if not is there any other clustring algorithm to solve this issue.

Comment: How far can be the points belonging to the same vertex?

Comment: let us say 10 units but the distance should be parameter controlled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had some fun, you can use the following simple algorithm.
The threshold can be changed and correspond somehow to your 10 units distance.

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66a059e3543c85bd)

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

struct Point {
    Point(int xx=0, int yy=0) : x(xx), y(yy) {}
    float x;
    float y;
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Point& p) {
        return os << "(" << p.x << ";" << p.y << ")";
    }
};

float distance(Point a, Point b) { return std::sqrt( (a.x - b.x) * (a.x - b.x) + (a.y - b.y) * (a.y - b.y)); }

Point average(const std::vector<Point>& vec) {
    Point p_avg;
    for (auto const &p : vec) {
        p_avg.x += p.x;
        p_avg.y += p.y;
    }
    p_avg.x /= vec.size();
    p_avg.y /= vec.size();
    return p_avg;
}

int main() {
    // your list of points in vertices
    std::vector<Point> vertices {Point(101, 202), Point(200, 200), Point(201, 202), Point(203, 204), Point(100, 400), Point(102, 402), Point(200, 400), Point(202, 401), Point(205, 405) };
    int threshold = 10; // change the value according to your context
    std::vector<std::vector<Point>> rect_vertices; // here we handle rect_vertices where vertices on one dimension are supposed to be neighbors 
    rect_vertices.push_back(std::vector<Point>{Point(100, 200)}); // we have to give an arbitrary Point here
    for (auto const &a : vertices) {
        std::size_t size = rect_vertices.size();
        bool is_added = false; // boolean to see if point a has a neighbor in rect_vertices
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++ i) {
            if (distance(rect_vertices[i][0],a) < threshold) {
                rect_vertices[i].push_back(a); // we add the neighbor a in the same dimension rect_vertices[i]
                is_added = true;
            }
        }
        if (!is_added) { rect_vertices.push_back(std::vector<Point>{a}); } // if no neighbor found then add an other vector<Point> to rect_vertices
    }
    for (auto const &v : rect_vertices) {
        for (auto const &p : v) {
            std::cout << p << " | ";  // print points in a neighborood
        }
        std::cout << " => avg : " << average(v) << std::endl; // print the average for each neighborood
    }
}
```

Results :

> (100;200) | (101;202) |  => avg : (100.5;201)
>
> (200;200) | (201;202) | (203;204) |  => avg : (201.333;202)
>
> (100;400) | (102;402) |  => avg : (101;401)
>
> (200;400) | (202;401) | (205;405) |  => avg : (202.333;402)

Comment: This only works when the points are nice in order. If you randomize the points you will end up with many different seeds that might be close together, i.e. you cannot chain if the points are randomized.

Comment: You are totally right :). I assumed this point with op example